# How can I get the buttons being generated in my table to have a dynamic ID?

Tags: jquery

I have a dynamically generated table in which I have buttons for which I need to be able to generate dynamic ids. I will be using the buttons later to (hopefully) grab the info from the table and create alerts based on the data. I can't get the buttons to generate a dynamic id though. I can get them to generate an id, but they have the same ID and aren't dynamic at all.

I've created a function that generates IDs and then appends the button class that I am targeting with the new ID. I have a table that is generated with jQuery using JSON data and all of that works. The code I am providing only generates the button IDs as "button2" which makes sense as that would be the next available index I suppose, but I don't know how to get it to generate the appropriate ID for the row in which in resides.

#### Simple html table that is populated with JSON data

```
<table id="schoolTable" class="table">
   <thead>
      <tr>
          <th><h4>School Name</h4></th>
          <th><h4>Status</h4></th>
          <th><h4>Chat</h4></th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="schoolTableBody">

  </tbody>
</table>
```

#### jQuery that creates the table and fills it

```
  populateTable = function() {
      $.getJSON("/assets/JSON/schools.JSON", function(result) {
          $.each(result, function(i){
              var schools = result.schools,
              output = "",
              schoolTableBody = $("#schoolTableBody");
                  for (var i = 0; i < schools.length; i++) {
                      buttonIdAdd = function() {
                          var button = $(".schoolInfoButton").attr("id", "button" + '-' + i);
                          $(".schoolInfoButton").append(button);
                  }
                          output +=
                          '<tr>' +
                          '<td>' +
                          '<h5>' +
                          schools[i].name +
                          '</h5>' +
                          '</td>' +
                          '<td class="schoolButtonHolder">' + 
                          '<button class="schoolInfoButton">' +
                          "Get" +
                          ' ' +
                          schools[i].topic +
                          ' ' +
                          "Information" +
                          '</button>' +
                          '</td>' +
                          '<td class="chatButtonHolder">' +
                          '<button class="schoolChatButton">' +
                          "Chat With" +
                          ' ' +
                          schools[i].topic +
                          '</button>' +
                          '</td>' +
                          '</tr>';
                   }
               schoolTableBody.html(output);  
               buttonIdAdd()     
          });
       });    
   }
```

I would like the buttons to have an ID based on the row they are in. I suppose the index? I am not sure how to do that as I thought the code provided could possibly work.

Comment: just use `'<button class="schoolInfoButton" id="button-' + i + '">' +` .. And remove all `buttonIdAdd` function .. No need for it

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef Thank you, that's exactly what I wanted...I tried something similar before but messed up the syntax I think because I was getting 'undefined'.

Comment: nvm sometimes small mistakes make a big problems .. you're totally welcome.. Have a great day :-)